# Laravel batches for execution

Tags: laravel, queue, batch-processing

I am fairly new with Laravel and I am planning to use massively the queues and batches. Today, while I was working on massing data import for performance testing, I found an issue with what we build and I need your help.

On the app, we will have queue jobs that will be running in queues, that part is clear. We have also batches for operations like data import or data export. I realised today that batches will just create jobs, but then, each job will be execute by the queue system (SQS for production), like any other queue job.

For us, that is an issue because that would mean that if we have a lot of elements in the queue, if a user start data import, he will need to wait for all the queue job before him to be executed.

I understand that I could create a queue "batch" and could give this queue a higher priority, but I have hoping a find a way to execute batch "on its own process", so that when a user start its import, it starts right away.

I am sorry if I am not clear, I can re-explain if required.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Ed

Comment: I'm relatively new to Laravel myself. Could [dispatchSync](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#synchronous-dispatching) possibly help? I've not yet used this myself, we do not have too much queuing at the moment.

Comment: I was this but I thought it was to optionally run a batch as a regular non-queued request (I guess this can be useful sometimes). I will try this and let you know then :) Thanks !

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately, like I thought, the dispatchSync will not trigger a batch work, it simply run a job in the current process. I am sure this is useful when you want to use a job to run code in the current request, but it doesn't work for importing data.